# How to add image in controller success message

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

How to add image in controller success message right now its showing only message i want to add image with success message in controller

```
 echo "<p><img width='100' height='100' alt='miley fac' src='image path is here'></p>";
    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
        $this->__('Your Success message')
    ) ;
```

Comment: what is your src, kindly paste here. I think the issues is in your image src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simply by just adding `<img>` tag

```
$k='<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b5e4c140f6c85eba651991235799ce61?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />';


 $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__($k));
```

Comment: Hi keyur , Its showing empty message window

Comment: img is exist or not ? in my sytem its working fine @MagentoAJ

Comment: yes image is exist if i copy that url in browser its showing image

Comment: just use my code and try and not change img src @MagentoAJ

Comment: well glad to hear that @MagentoAJ